# jQuery using parent method to add new row

Tags: jquery, row, parent

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2XJXu/) I have a html code where I have input textbox planted in a row. How can I use the '+' button in the same table while using ONLY `parent()` function to create a new row within the table that contains another input textbox?

I have some sample jQuery code here but they don't really work:

```
          $(".plus").live("click", function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent(".iteration");
 parent.after('<table width="100%" border="0" bordercolor="#000000"><tr><td colspan="2"><label><input type="text" value="Create a task for this iteration" size="75%" height="25px"/></label></td></tr></table>');

        var nbinput = parent.find("input[type='text']").length;
        if(nbinput == 5)
            parent.find(".plus").attr("disabled","disabled");
        else if(nbinput == 2)
            parent.find(".moins").attr("disabled","");
    });

    $(".moins").live("click", function(){       
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent(".iteration");
        parent.children("input").last().remove();
        var nbinput = parent.find("input[type='text']").length;
        if(nbinput == 4)
            parent.find(".plus").attr("disabled","");
        else if(nbinput == 1)
            parent.find(".moins").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
```

Comment: at a quick glance i see that your (function() {... doesn't start with the $ it should be $(function() {... but maybe that was just a copy paste issue

Comment: i just got enough points to voteup dude. Gonna do that in a bit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's your series of `parent()`. It looks like you're not factoring in elements such as the td and tr. just try `var parent = $('.iteration')`

I don't know the exact expected outcome for the UI so i can't say more beyond that.

Comment: hey i managed to get it somehow and i realised the parent().parent().parent(); will be sufficient. do you know why would anyone wants to do the same thing but specify the class/id in this way: parent().parent().parent(".iteration"); ??

Comment: No i can't see why someone would do that. this isn't your code?

Answer (score 2):

Well, some simplification will go a long way:

```
var parent, attribute_toggle;

attribute_toggle = function (nbinput, parent) {
    switch(nbinput) {
        case 5:
            parent.find('.plus').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        case 4:
            parent.find('.plus').removeAttr('disabled');
        case 2:
            parent.find('.moins').removeAttr('disabled');
        case 1:
            parent.find('.moins').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
};

$('.plus').live('click', function() {
    parent = $(this).parents('.iteration:first');
    parent.after('... removed for brevity ...');
    attribute_toggle(parent.find('input:text').length, parent);
});
$('.moins').live('click', function() {
    parent = $(this).parents('.iteration:first');
    parent.children('input:last').remove();
    attribute_toggle(parent.find('input:text').length, parent);
});
```

*Updated to be easier to read, and merged the switch into a function.*

There, now that it is a bit more legible, explain what happens when you try to run this code, and contrast that with what you would like to happen.